# How to put a TextEdit inside a cell in QTableWidget - Pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, resize, qtextedit

I managed to put a TextEdit inside a cell in my QTableWidget using this code:

```
for i in range(10):
    rowCount = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
    self.tableWidget_3.insertRow(rowCount)

    combo = QTextEdit(self)
    self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(i, 0, combo)
    self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(i, 0).setText(str(per_picture[i]))
    
    #Adjusting the TextEdit
    docHeight = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(i, 0).document().size().height()
    self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(i, 0).setMinimumHeight(docHeight)
```

All is working well until I to the part of adjusting the size of the TextEdit to match the size of the text. The 2 Text edit seem to overlap when adjusting the size like the one in this

[image: picture of the overlapping].

How can I fix this 2 TextEdit overlapping?
How can I resize a TextEdit inside a TableWidget?

These are the file needed to reproduce the problem:

MyApp.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

text = """In order to have a complete sentence, the sentence must 
        have a minimum of three word types: a subject, a verb, 
        and an object. In most cases, the subject is a noun or 
        a pronoun."""

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("MyApp.ui", self)
        self.tableWidget_3.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget_3.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget_3.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        for i in range(10):
            rowCount = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
            self.tableWidget_3.insertRow(rowCount)
            combo = QTextEdit(self)
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(i, 0, combo)
            self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(i, 0).setText(text)
            #self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(i, 0).adjustSize()
            docHeight = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(i, 0).document().size().height()
            self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(i, 0).setMinimumHeight(int(docHeight))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myApp = MyApp()
myApp.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except:
    print('Closing Window')
```

MyApp.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>561</width>
    <height>421</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Editor</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>561</width>
     <height>421</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <property name="sizeConstraint">
     <enum>QLayout::SetNoConstraint</enum>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_3">
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>New Column</string>
       </property>
      </column>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "adjusting the size of the TextEdit to match the size of the text"? Are you referring to the `setMinimumHeight()` of your code, or resizing using the header of the table? Also, please provide a [mre].

Comment: I'm referring to the `setMinimumHeight()`. I only put here the part of the code that adds row and TextEdit to the TableWidget, should I add the part of the code necessary to run/show the TableWidget?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error using the basic code you provided, so, yes, a full MRE will certainly help. Consider that it should be a code that we could directly copy, paste and run, possibly without any substantial modification. Besides that, there's really no need to always access `self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(i, 0)`: you already have set the `combo` local variable, just use that, it will make your code more readable.

Comment: I added the part of the code required to show the problem. Those are 2 files are named `MyApp.py` and `MyApp.ui`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that setting the minimum size of the cell widget does *not* set the minimum size of the section. By default, sections all have a standard item size (computed using the default font and system/style configuration), and since the minimum size of the widget is not taken into account, the result is that you only see part of the editor.

Since you hidden the vertical header, I suppose you want the rows to resize automatically, and that can be done by properly implementing the `sizeHint` of the editor. Then, you can install an event filter on the table so that it will automatically try to resize the rows according to the contents:

```
class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.updateGeometry)

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        if self.toPlainText():
            doc = self.document().clone()
            width = self.width() - self.frameWidth() * 2
            if self.verticalScrollBar().isVisible():
                width -= self.verticalScrollBar().width()
            doc.setTextWidth(width)
            height = round(doc.size().height())
        else:
            height = self.fontMetrics().height()
            height += self.document().documentMargin() * 2
        height += self.frameWidth() * 2
        hint.setHeight(height)
        return hint


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("MyApp.ui", self)
        self.tableWidget_3.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget_3.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget_3.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        for i in range(10):
            rowCount = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
            self.tableWidget_3.insertRow(rowCount)
            combo = TextEdit(self)
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(i, 0, combo)
            combo.setText(text)
            combo.textChanged.connect(
                lambda i=i: self.tableWidget_3.resizeRowToContents(i))
        self.tableWidget_3.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == event.Resize:
            QTimer.singleShot(0, self.tableWidget_3.resizeRowsToContents)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

<sup>Note: you didn't properly set the layout on the main window: you just added a "floating" layout that is completely ignored when the window is resized; move the table outside of it, remove that layout, right click on an empty area of the window, and select a vertical or horizontal layout from the "Lay out" submenu.</sup>
<sup>Also, for future reference, if you only need a few widgets for your examples, you don't need to use a Designer file: just create a basic QWidget subclass, set a layout for it, and add the widgets you need to use; your example could have been reduced to just 3 more lines in your `MyApp` class without the need for the UI file:

`layout = QVBoxLayout(self)`

`self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()`

`layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)`

This will make your example more simple and will also makes things easier for us, since we only need to copy/paste one file.</sup>

Comment: I tried it and It worked, Thank You!

Comment: Just one thing hard for me to understand, How do you use the `resizeEvent` and `eventFilter` method without calling them.

Comment: Forgive me if it's obvious, I'm just new in Python OOP and I'm just practicing it with PyQt5.

Comment: Those are method *overrides*, and you're not supposed to call them at all, because Qt will call them whenever required. Overriding means that we know that those functions will be called at a certain point, and we *override* their behavior by providing a custom implementation. In the case of the `eventFilter`, using `self.tableWidget_3.installEventFilter(self)` means that *all* events that would be sent to the table widget will be intercepted by the `eventFilter` of MyApp (`self`) and eventually sent to the widget, since we overrode `eventFilter`, we can intercept those events, and since we ->

Comment: -> need to know when a resize event is going to be sent to the table widget, we can check if the event is of that type and do something: in this case we only need to do a delayed call to `resizeRowsToContents` (it has to be delayed, because it takes some time to item views to adjust their contents in the scroll area), but for other complex situations we can even alter the behavior or even completely ignore the event (by returning `True`). Note that I just realized that the `resizeEvent` of `TextEdit` is actually useless for this situation, so I removed it.

Comment: That said, method overriding is one of the most important aspects in OOP and subclassing, since it allows to alter the behavior of a class. For instance, the most common case for widgets is to override the `mousePressEvent`: you obviously don't call it directly, but you know that it will be called by Qt whenever the widget receives a mouse button press, and overriding that method allows us to do anything we want with that event, from a simple `print('mouse press')` to more complex things, like showing a dialog or changing the color of the widget depending on the cursor position on the widget.

Comment: Ahhhh, I now understand it. You helped me so much with this, Thank you!