# Connecting a function to a pyqt5 QTextEdit that was created and added to a QTableWidget inside a loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, lambda, pyqt5, qtextedit

I am currently creating an application that helps analyse chat logs that have two participants. A bot and a customer.
My goal is to add a QTableWidget that has QTextEdit elements in it to my application's main window. The user can then select the text inside those QTextEdits. Once selected, the text background color of the selected text should be changed.

example:
Suspendisse suscipit, **tellus ut varius** aliquam, tortor enim placerat sem, sit amet porta eros tellus ultrices risus.

The user double clicks and selects "tellus ut varius" from the above text. The background color is now changed. If they select those words again, the change is reverted.

I am using this solution to add the QTextEdits to the QTableWidget:
[How to put a TextEdit inside a cell in QTableWidget - Pyqt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69300654/how-to-put-a-textedit-inside-a-cell-in-qtablewidget-pyqt5)

The table is populated inside the following loop:

```
    def populate_chat(self):
            self.chat.setColumnCount(1)
            self.chat.setRowCount(len(example_chat_list))
            for idx, message in enumerate(example_chat_list):
                oname1, oname2 = 'chat_bubble_bot', 'chat_bubble_customer'
                if idx % 2 == 0:
                    combo = TextEdit(self, objectName=oname1) 
                else:
                    combo = TextEdit(self, objectName=oname2) 
                self.chat.setCellWidget(idx, 0, combo)
                combo.setText(message)
                combo.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.test)
                combo.textChanged.connect(
                lambda idx=idx: self.chat.resizeRowToContents(idx))
            self.chat.installEventFilter(self)
```

The goal is to have this function change the text background:

```
    def test(self):
        cursor = self.exampleelement.textCursor()
        current_color = cursor.charFormat().background().color().rgb()
        format = QTextCharFormat()
        if cursor.hasSelection() and current_color != 4294901760:
            format.setBackground(Qt.red)
        else:
            format.setBackground(QColor(70, 70, 70))
        cursor.setCharFormat(format)
```

I am having trouble referring to the QTextEdit element (exampleelement in the code block) when calling the test function.
The chat bubbles for the participants are styled differently in a separate stylesheet where they are referred to by name. That is why I have kept the names of the objects different for the participants. I have also tried enumerating the names like chat_bubble_customer0. chat_bubble_customer1 and so on, but was still unsuccessful in transferring the name of the element over to the test function.

Comment: You can find the *sender* of the signal in the function that calls it, `textEdit = `self.sender()`. Note that changing the caracter format at each position change is usually not a very good idea.

Comment: Thank you! I will try the sender method. 
Is there a better way to implement the highlight function without the user having to trigger the highlighting manually?

Comment: Are you just trying to change the color of selection and use a custom one instead of the default?

Comment: Yes. The sections that are highlighted in the custom color will be replaced by placeholders in order to anonymize certain parts of conversations before the logs are stored. I still have to figure out how to do that second part.

Comment: You can set the default selection color in the widget stylesheet: `combo.setStyleSheet('selection-background-color: red;')`.

Comment: Yes, I have set a default color in the external stylesheet for the application. Once a user selects some text in the QTextEdit it gets highlighted in red by changing the text background color. That functionality is implemented in the test() function. If they select the same text again, it gets set back to the default color (70,70,70).

Comment: Please make your objective more clear, right now your function may work erratically if the selection is changed in different ways. I suggest you to [edit] your post to better explain the expected behavior.

Comment: I have added the following to my post:
example: 
Suspendisse suscipit, **tellus ut varius** aliquam, tortor enim placerat sem, sit amet porta eros tellus ultrices risus.

The user double clicks and selects "tellus ut varius" from the above text. The background color is now changed. If they select those words again, the change is reverted.

it is working as intended now that I have implemented the self.sender() method. Thank you again.
I was just asking if there is a better way to implement it since you did point out that doing it this way is usually not a very good idea.

Comment: It *seem* to work, but it doesn't work in the proper way, as you're relying on hard-coded colors and overriding the format (which is also unreliable as the selection could start in another position). Even if it works right now, you'll probably have problems in the future: try to unset the default color and see what happens when changing selection using keyboard navigation (shift arrows). Anyway, a slightly better implementation would use `format.clearBackground()`, but a *proper* approach should keep track of selected fragments. In any case, using a subclass would certainly make things easier.

Comment: I had been looking for something like format.clearBackground() but was unable to find that specific function. You are right. It does work better. I am not sure how I would keep track of selected fragments yet, but I will probably have to find a way to do so in order to generate the final output. I am pretty new to PyQt so I do not know how to use a subclass to make things easier. I will have to do some research into it.